# What if the cauchy product of two series in $\mathbf{Z}$ is null

Tags: sequences-and-series, convolution, laurent-series

I have a problem I do not find a solution. Given two series
$\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbf{Z}}$
 and 
$\left(b_n\right)_{n \in \mathbf{Z}}$
which have a cauchy product 
$\left(c_n\right)_{n \in \mathbf{Z}} = 
\left(\sum_{i \in \mathbf{Z}}{a_i b_{n-i}}\right)_{n \in \mathbf{Z}}$ and $\forall n,\sum_{i\in\mathbf{Z}}{\left|a_ib_{n-i}\right|}<\infty$.

Do $\left(c_n\right)_{n \in \mathbf{Z}}=0$ implies 
$\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbf{Z}}=0$ or
$\left(b_n\right)_{n \in \mathbf{Z}}=0$?

It is true if $\exists n_0, \forall n<n_0, a_n=0$ (like in [traditional formal Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_Laurent_series#Formal_Laurent_series)).  I can not find a demonstration or a counterexample for the general case.

Comment: Your sum over $i\in \mathbb Z$ need not be well defined without further restrictions - in what order are the terms to be added?

Comment: I supposed implicitely that $\forall n, \sum_{i\in\mathbf{Z}}{\left|a_ib_{n-i}\right|}$ is defined. I add it to the question.

Comment: What if $a_n=1$ for all $n$ and $b_0=1, b_1=-1$ and $b_n=0$ otherwise?

Comment: It is a good idea, but $\sum{\left|a_i b_{n-i}\right|}$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at some Fourier series (two functions with product zero), and use their coefficients.  Example:
$$
a_0 = \frac{1}{2},\qquad a_{n} = \frac{1}{\pi i n}, n \text{ odd},
\qquad a_n = 0, \text{otherwise}
$$

$$
b_0 = \frac{1}{2},\qquad b_{n} = \frac{-1}{\pi i n}, n \text{ odd},
\qquad b_n = 0, \text{otherwise}
$$

Comment: I am not sure to understand. $c_0 = \sum_j{a_j b_{-j}} = 1/4 + \sum_{j \neq 0}{\frac{1}{-(2j+1)^2}\frac{1}{-\pi}} = 0$, but $c_1 = 0 + \sum_{i \neq -1,1}{\frac{1}{(i+1)(i-1)}\frac{1}{-\pi}}\neq 0$.

Comment: The last term is of course c_1 = 0 + \sum_{i \neq -1,1}{\frac{1}{(2i+1)(2i-1)}\frac{1}{-\pi}}\neq 0. Too late to edit.

Comment: The sum of any two odd number is even, but $1$ is odd.  So $c_1 = a_0b_1+a_1b_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by induction:

$n=0$.
If $a_0b_0=0$, one of them is zero.
If both are zero, repeat the problem
with sums from $1$ to $\infty$
until the first non-zero one is found.
If all are zero, we are done.

We assume $a_0 = 0$ and $b_0 \ne 0$.

$n > 0$.
Suppose $c_n = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i b_{n-i} = 0$
and $a_i = 0$ for $i$ from $0$ to $n-1$.
Then $a_i b_{n-i} = 0$
for $i$ from $0$ to $n-1$,
so $0 = c_n = a_n b_0$.
Since $b_0 \ne 0$,
$a_n = 0$.

Therefore all the $a_n = 0$.

Comment: It is not possible to do that, the sum $c_n=\sum_{i \in\mathbf Z}{a_i b_{n-1}}$ are on an infinite number of items.

Comment: This is the solution for index set $\mathbb N$.  And (essentially) what the OP means by "traditional formal Laurent series".